VectorLayer vs VectorTileLayer feature.getId() differences in OpenLayers 9 + GeoServer
I'm perplexed on why the IDs of my features are formatted differently depending on if I create a VectorLayer or a VectorTileLayer out of the same set of features. It's possible this has to do more with GeoServer too, I'm not really sure.
In GeoServer, I have an SQL View defined where I check the field huc_8 as my "identifier" column. An additional setting I have set in the PostGIS DB store that this layer comes from on GeoServer is to expose the primary keys. If I preview the vector layer in GeoServer and click on a feature, it returns all the fields like I expect, plus the field fid and the field huc_8 since I opted to expose the primary keys. An example of those fields' data looks like this in GeoServer:
| fid            | huc_8  | 
|----------------|--------|
| huc_8.12345678 |12345678|

I tried to preview the layer in GeoServer's GWC and while it displays normally, clicking it does nothing so I can't figure out if it comes back with both an fid field and the huc_8 field or just huc_8. The ability to click on a feature and return attributes in GWC used to work (v.2.23 last I tried), but opening the browser console gives errors for GeoServer's code now in v.2.25 (some function they try to call in the process of displaying the attributes doesn't exist anymore - it has nothing to do with my layer).
Now, in OpenLayers when I try to use the layer in my own application, I have noticed when I create a VectorLayer, click on a single feature and retrieve it's feature ID, I get an ID of huc_8.12345678. However, if I use this same layer and create a VectorTileLayer instead, clicking on a single feature yields a feature ID formatted like the huc_8 field: 12345678. Do VectorTileLayers not contain an fid field because they're not really features, but rather tiles being displayed?
This is how I create a VectorLayer:
const hucUrl =
  `https://blahblahblah.com/geoserver/datastore/wfs?` +
  "service=wfs&" +
  "version=2.0.0&" +
  "request=GetFeature&" +
  `typeNames=datastore:huc_8&` +
  "outputFormat=application/json&" +
  "srsName=EPSG:3857";

const hucSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON({
    dataProjection: "EPSG:3857",
    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",
  }),
  loader: function (extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
    const url = hucUrl;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    const onError = function () {
      console.log("error on wfs request");
    };
    xhr.onerror = onError;
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        const features: Feature<Geometry>[] = hucSource
          .getFormat()
          .readFeatures(xhr.responseText) as Feature<Geometry>[];
        hucSource.addFeatures(features);
        success(features);
      } else {
        onError();
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  },
});

export const huc8Layer = new VectorLayer({
  source: hucSource,
  style: hucStyleFunc as StyleFunction,
  properties: { name: "huc_8" },
  zIndex: 1,
});


This is how I create a VectorTileLayer:
const hucVectorSource = new VectorTileSource({
  url:
    "https://blahblahblah.com/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/" +
    "datastore" +
    "%3A" +
    "huc_8" +
    "@EPSG%3A" +
    "900913" +
    "@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf",
  format: new MVT({
    featureClass: Feature,
  }),
});

export const huc8Layer = new VectorTileLayer({
  opacity: 1,
  visible: true,
  declutter: true,
  source: hucVectorSource,
  style: hucStyleFunc as StyleFunction,
  properties: { name: "huc8" },
  zIndex: 1,
});

This is my function to get the feature ID when someone clicks one of the features on the map:
export const onClickSelectHuc = (e, hucLayer) => {
  hucLayer.getFeatures(e.pixel).then(function (features) {
    const feature = features[0];
    const fid = feature.getId();
    return fid
}


my guess is that vector tiles don't have fids, but it could also be due to the datastore being a view, did you provide a metadata table - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html

The MVT format will set an id if you supply it with an idProperty as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html
